# Einstein predictive email recommendation(SFMC) on product out of stock when email is clicked?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Here's the scenario on Einstein SFMC

Einstein-element is added to email which sell iPhones, customer receive the email and iPhone recommendations in Einstein module - for example iPhone 9 and XS.
Then 4 days later customer opens the email, but at that time iPhone 9 is out of the stock.

What Einstein module shows to this customer in this case? Is there still iPhone 9 or does it change the product if iPhone 9 is no more in the webshop?

Comment: I believe einstein is send time personization, not real time, so they would still see what was originally sent in email, regardless of current stock.

Comment: Thank you.. Any work arounds to achieve the real time personalisation?

Comment: You would have to either create your own dynamic image server or use something like mobile ink or liveclicker.  Please note that this would only change the image displayed. Any HTML, copy, links or alt text, etc. would all be static.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the email recommendations are delivered as an open-time recommendations and are activated when a user opens the email. The logic and scenarios are processed immediately before they see the recommendation. This means that behaviour collected after the email is sent out, is still taken into consideration when selecting products to be recommended.

However the images are pre-built, based on catalogue data and HTML templates as configured within the email recommendation app in SFMC - hence each product or content recommendation is generated ahead of time and stored, to ensure that the image is instantly available.

By pre-processing all the displays for each product or content recommendation and processing the logic on open-time, the recommendations should be up-to-date and served without unnecessary delay.

What you are seeing, is the 72 hour cache, which prevents the sold out items from being removed, if OnlineAvailability is set to false within this period. It is not possible to reduce this caching period, but you can improve this with one simple trick - which might be helpful in some use cases.

The cache is linked to the hash of a recommendation. E.g:

```
<a href="https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5544abcdef1234/l/1/%%emailaddr%%">
<img src="https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5544abcdef1234/i/1/%%emailaddr%%">
</a>
```

The email hash (*5544abcdef1234* above) can be found under ID on the email recommendation main screen.

If you send emails daily, you can use different hash values, to get recommendations refreshed more frequently than each 72 hours. However each email sent, will not exclude sold out items before 72 hours have passed.

You can set up a new Email Hash like this:

1. Choose the Predictive Email from the Personalization Builder App in the top navigation.
2. Click the Create New Logic button
3. Name the Email Template under the Unique Name field
4. Choose the Type of Catalog if you have multiple (product/content) setup.
5. Click the Create button